# Angular - Use the same component in a material stepper

Tags: angular

I'm looking to achieve the following through Angular 10

- I have a component that loads a stl cad file using threejs.
- I have a wizard where I ask various questions related to the loaded stl cad file
- I use the angular material step component for my stepper / wizard

I would like to have the same instance of the stl cad component in each of the steps in the stepper and only change the rotation of the cad object in the component in each step. I currently do something like this which just shows the stl cad on the last stepper  - nothing for the previous steps.

The name of the component is app-cad. As you can see I have two instances -one in each step but only the second one shows.

This is the html for the app-cad component. I basically draw onto this canvas

```
<div class="container" >   
    <div  class="child-1" >     
        <canvas #rendererCanvasObj id="renderCanvasObj"></canvas>                          
    </div>      
</div>
```

and this is some of the code for the stepper

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>

<mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" [editable]="isEditable">

    <div class="container" fxLayoutGap="30px" fxLayout="row"  >   

        <mat-card class="example-card" [class.mat-elevation-z10]=true>
            <mat-card-header>
                <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
                <mat-card-title>Test</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>                    
                <app-cad></app-cad>                                                                                    
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-actions>                    
            </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
                
    </div>
      
</mat-step>

<mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" [editable]="isEditable">

    <div class="container" fxLayoutGap="30px" fxLayout="row"  >   

        <mat-card class="example-card" [class.mat-elevation-z10]=true>
            <mat-card-header>
                <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
                <mat-card-title>Test 2</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>                    
                <app-cad></app-cad>                                                                                    
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-actions>                    
            </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
                
    </div>
      
</mat-step>
```

Comment: Have you set the FormGroups in the TS file correctly? And you might have to use the `<form>` tag instead of the `<div>` tag to then set the FormGroup.
Check this StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rmerbxgdxqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-label-position-bottom-example.ts

Comment: The form part is ok as this is different in each step and this part works. The issue I face is the CAD component. When I insert this into the mat-step stepper multiple times it only shows once and it's always the last reference. The component is called 'app-cad' above. Ideally what I want is for the stepper to use the same instance throughout the stepper but I'm not sure how to accomplish this

Comment: Hello,
do you have the same scene for both steppers ?  if so, you have to create for each stepper its own scene.